# angular appBootstrap method

Tags: angular

I'm having some hard time finding why I need to call this method.
This line to be more specific: **if ((window as any).appBootstrap) (window as any).appBootstrap();**

```
platformBrowserDynamic()
    .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .then(value => {
        if ((window as any).appBootstrap) (window as any).appBootstrap();
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

When I create a new angular project it doesnt have that and works fine.
Does any one have any idea where should I be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, that line is not necessary to be called in order to run an normal angular app, however, if it is needed to bootstrap your app correctly you have to look for a third library or some module that required that object.